# Ambiguous reference to subscript with string literal and NSObject subscript type

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3, nsobject

I am upgrading my project to swift 3.0 and I am getting an error on userInfo["aps"].   I have tried putting a question mark and explanation point between it but no luck

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
                    //Do stuff
                }
            } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
                //Do stuff
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Always include the exact text of the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, **use Swift collection types**, the Foundation collection types don't provide any type information about their contents.

First of all use the actual signature of the delegate method, marking the method as private and keeping the old signature is a bad compromise. However consider that the method is deprecated.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification 
                      userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any])
```

The `JSON` collection types are always `[String:Any]` (dictionary) or `[[String:Any]]` (array)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification 
                      userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any])

    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String:Any] {
            if let message = alert["message"] as? String {
                //Do stuff
            }
        } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? String {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3 no longer automatically bridges value types (`String`, that is the type of "aps") to Objective-C reference types (`NSString`, a descendant of the required type `NSObject` key of your dictionary)

So you must do:

`userInfo["aps" as NSString]`

You might also save yourself some trouble having to repeat this bridging technique: get the rest into native Swift form as quickly as possible:

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps" as NSString] as? [String: AnyObject] {
    if let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String: String], message = alert["message"] {
        // message is now a Swift String
    }
    else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? String {
        // alert is now a Swift String
    }
}
```

Comment: The suggestion to bridge strings to `NSString` in Swift 3 is quite bad. Consider the crucial changes `AnyObject` -> `Any` and `[NSObject : AnyObject]` -> `[AnyHashable : Any]` in Swift 3